# Materialize stepper back button issue on double click

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, materialize

I am using Materialize Stepper in my project to display multi forms, everything is working fine and i noticed that when double click on back button all the content become blank and we have to refresh the page.

```
'''https://codepen.io/flist/pen/mqXemY'''
```

Please check the above codepen page and when you click next button and from second step if you tried to double click on back button all content will be washout.

If anyone can check and suggest some solution that will be great help.

Comment: Do you require back button at step 1?

Comment: @Tales, thanks for checking... not in the first step from step 2 onward i need a back button

Comment: hiding it on 1st step will stop the double click issue right?

Comment: check this link i removed back button from first step,https://codepen.io/jasirec/pen/qBXQLZo